# LDAP Authentication - SQL Server 2017 on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, active-directory, sql-server-2017

We have installed SQL Server 2017 on Linux server. I am able to connect SQL Server locally as well remotely but with local user access.

I have my AD account created and have AD server information. Can you please help me how can I connect using my AD account to SQL Server 2017 on Linux remotely? I heard something about LDAP Authentication. Is it possible to use this concept without adding Linux server to AD domain? Our security team does not allow to add Linux server in Active Directory group.

Comment: I think you can't do it without adding the server to the AD.

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication), but the sql server hosting machine has to be added in AD, otherwise you can not use AD authentication at all.